# Soma de number em typescript está resultando em NaN

Tags: javascript, typescript, nan

Estou fazendo um código para obter a média de valores de uma lista, entretanto o resultado está sendo NaN (not a number).

```
import { SimpleTableAnalysis } from '../model/SimpleTableAnalysis'
import { UserInfo } from '../model/UserInfo';

export class MeanAnalysis implements SimpleTableAnalysis {

    public analysis(userInfoList: Array<UserInfo>): number{

        var sum: number = 0.0;

        userInfoList.forEach(userInfo => sum += userInfo.getCredit() );

        return sum/(userInfoList.length);
    }
}
```

O erro acontece dentro do forEach, o código reconhece o valor do método 'getCredit()', que retorna number, e é possivel realizar soma nele, entretanto com a variável 'sum' (variável externa ao forEach) me retorna NaN mesmo em um for normal.

Segue a conversão para javascript:

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
    value: !0
});
var MeanAnalysis = function() {
    function e() {}
    return e.prototype.analysis = function(e) {
        var n = 0;
        return e.forEach(function(e) {
            return n += e.getCredit()
        }), n / e.length
    }, e
}();
exports.MeanAnalysis = MeanAnalysis;
```

Como soluciono isso?

Answer (score 1):

Com o código que você passou não da pra ter certeza se o retorno do método `getCredit()` é realmente um número em todos os casos. No entanto, segue um exemplo de um código funcionalmente igual ao seu.

Note que, esse código irá retornar um `NaN` no caso do `array` ser vázio. Talvez seja esse o caso em sua aplicação, você poderia verificar de antemão se o `array.length === 0` e retornar um valor válido, ou jogar um `Error` caso necessário.

```js
var nums = [
  1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
];

function media(numArray) {
  if(numArray.length === 0) return 0;
  return numArray.reduce((sum, item) => sum += item, 0) / numArray.length;
}

console.log(media(nums));
```

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver o problema, o erro era que eu estava buscando os dados de um arquivo .csv, porém eu me lembrei de tratar apenas o cabeçalho e não as linhas em branco o que resultava em alguns elementos NaN.